# Why do we subtract the “transport velocity” from the "domain velocity" in ALE?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

[image]

Why do we subtract the “transport velocity” from the "domain velocity" in Arbitrary Lagrange Eulerian framework when writing the Navier Stokes equation?

Book: Cardiovascular mathematics Modeling and simulation of the circulatory system by Luca Formaggia, Alfio Quarteroni, Allesandro Veneziani

Comment: May i ask what books is this? For additional context

Comment: It is "Cardiovascular mathematics Modeling and simulation of the circulatory system" by Luca Formaggia, Alfio Quarteroni, Allesandro Veneziani.    Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ALE, you transform the problem from a moving domain to a different domain. So, you will also have to transform the spatial and time derivatives in the governing equations from the moving domain to this new domain. Upon doing so, the time derivative introduces the extra term you are referring to $w \cdot \nabla u$. For more details, see pgs. 7-8 in this [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.921.2702&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the paper. I will read it and may I ask you please further questions if I had after reading it?

Comment: of course, you may ask